How to make bindingsource add new only limit one row in DataGridView with vb.net
I'm Trying to make bindingsource add new only limit one row in DataGridView with vb.net So if the user doubles tab in the keyboard, two empty rows appear in the DataGridView or  avoiding double addnew() Like the GIF file below but in the grid it doesn't mean only 1 record in one row.
And is it possible I want When Form Load and first focus in row datagridview so I can select and edit in the first row datagridview with the keyboard?.
Is the code method I use wrong and do I have to loop to check for an empty column in the Button Event (btnsave)?
Please Guide me
Thanks
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Dapper

Public Class autocompledatagridview
    Inherits Form
    Private dictProducts As Dictionary(Of String, ProductFinaltesting)
    Private BindingSource1 As BindingSource = Nothing
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
        updateDataSource()
    End Sub
    Protected Sub updateDataSource()
        dictProducts = ProductFinaltestingService.GetDistinctProducts().
    ToDictionary(Function(p) p.ToString(), Function(p) p)
        BindingSource1 = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = New BindingList(Of ProductFinaltesting)}
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
        DataGridView1.Columns("Unit").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns("No").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns("Prp").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns("Prs").ReadOnly = True
        BindingSource1.AddNew()
        DataGridView1.Select()
    End Sub
 Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(
      sender As Object,
      e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles _
      DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
        If TypeOf e.Control Is TextBox Then
            Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
            Dim tb = DirectCast(e.Control, TextBox)
            If dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
                If tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Count = 0 Then
                    tb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
                    tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(dictProducts.Keys.ToArray())
                End If
                tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
            Else
                tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(
       sender As Object,
       e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) _
       Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index AndAlso
           e.RowIndex <> dgv.NewRowIndex Then
            Dim key As String

            If dgv.IsCurrentCellInEditMode Then
                Dim p = dictProducts.Values.
                FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.ProductName.
                Equals(e.FormattedValue.
                ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))

                If p IsNot Nothing Then
                    key = p.ToString()
                Else
                    key = e.FormattedValue.ToString()
                End If
            Else
                key = dgv(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value?.ToString().Trim()
            End If
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(key) OrElse
           Not dictProducts.ContainsKey(key) Then
                Dim boundItem = DirectCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinaltesting)
                boundItem.Unit = Nothing
                boundItem.Prp = Nothing
                boundItem.Prs = Nothing
                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Invalid Product!"
                Btnsave.Visible = False
                dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("PRP").Index, e.RowIndex)
                dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("PRS").Index, e.RowIndex)
                e.Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
 Private Sub setno()
        Dim i = 1
        Dim bs = TryCast(BindingSource1.DataSource, BindingList(Of ProductFinaltesting))
        For Each row As ProductFinaltesting In bs
            row.No = i
            i += 1
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidated(
       sender As Object,
       e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidated
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
            Dim p As ProductFinaltesting = Nothing
            Dim key = dgv(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value?.ToString().Trim()

            If key Is Nothing Then Return
            If dictProducts.TryGetValue(key, p) Then
                Dim boundItem = TryCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinaltesting)
 If p.Unit <> boundItem.Unit Or p.Prp <> boundItem.Prp Or p.Prs <> boundItem.Prs Then
                    boundItem.Unit = p.Unit
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    boundItem.Prp = p.Prp
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Prp").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    boundItem.Prs = p.Prs
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Prs").Index, e.RowIndex)

                End If
                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = Nothing
                Btnsave.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(
        sender As Object,
        e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        Dim src = DirectCast(dgv.DataSource, BindingSource)
        If src.Count = e.RowIndex Then Return
        If e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Columns("ProductName").Index Then
            Dim p As ProductFinaltesting = Nothing
            Dim key = dgv(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value?.ToString().Trim()

            If key Is Nothing Then Return
            If dictProducts.TryGetValue(key, p) Then
                Dim boundItem = TryCast(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, ProductFinaltesting)
   If p.Unit <> boundItem.Unit Or p.Prp <> boundItem.Prp Or p.Prs <> boundItem.Prs Then
                    boundItem.Unit = p.Unit
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Unit").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    boundItem.Prp = p.Prp
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Prp").Index, e.RowIndex)
                    boundItem.Prs = p.Prs
                    dgv.UpdateCellValue(dgv.Columns("Prs").Index, e.RowIndex)
                End If
                dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = Nothing
            End If
            setno()
        End If
 Dim QTY As Integer = Nothing
        If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("QTY").Value IsNot Nothing Then
            If Not Integer.TryParse(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("QTY").Value.ToString(), QTY) Then
                QTY = 0
            End If
        Else
            QTY = 0
        End If
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("QTY").Value = QTY
    End Sub
    Private Sub Btnsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnsave.Click

    End Sub
'Update code
 Private Function GetSELECT() As ProductFinaltesting
        Return If(DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count = 0, Nothing, TryCast(DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).OwningRow.DataBoundItem, ProductFinaltesting))
    End Function
 
   Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        If keyData = Keys.Tab AndAlso CBool(Keys.Enter) Then
            Dim SelectDgv = GetSELECT()
            If Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
   If Not DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).Any(Function(cell) String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.FormattedValue?.ToString())) Then
                    BindingSource1.AddNew()
                Else
                    DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1)
                    DataGridView1.BeginEdit(False)

                End If
            Else
            End If
            Return True
        ElseIf keyData = Keys.F1 AndAlso CBool(Keys.Enter) Then
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(5)
            DataGridView1.BeginEdit(False)
        Else
        End If
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function

End Class

Public Class ProductFinaltesting
    '<Browsable(False)>
    'Public Property Font As String = "☑️"
    Public Property No As Integer?
    Public Property ProductName As String
    Public Property Unit As String
    Public Property Prp As Integer?
    Public Property Prs As Integer?
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{ProductName}"
    End Function

End Class
Public Class ProductFinaltestingService
    Private Shared Function GetOledbConnectionString() As String
        Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                    Data Source=|DataDirectory|\test04102024.accdb;
                    Persist Security Info=False;"
    End Function
    ' ...
    Friend Shared Function GetDistinctProducts() As IEnumerable(Of ProductFinaltesting)
        Dim sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ProductName, Unit,Prp,Prs 
                       FROM Products 
                       ORDER BY ProductName"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of ProductFinaltesting)(sql)
        End Using
    End Function
    Friend Shared Function GetProducts() As IEnumerable(Of ProductFinaltesting)
        Dim sql = "SELECT ProductName, Unit,Prp,Prs 
                       FROM Products 
                       ORDER BY ProductName"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            Return _conn.Query(Of ProductFinaltesting)(sql)
        End Using
    End Function
    Public Sub UpdateProducts(ByVal Obj As ProductFinaltesting)
        Dim sql = "UPDATE Products Set Unit=@Unit,Prp=@Prp,Prs=@Prs WHERE ProductName=@ProductName;"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            _conn.Execute(sql, New With {
    Key Obj.Unit,
    Key Obj.Prp,
    Key Obj.Prs,
    Key Obj.ProductName
})
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class





A one-row-only grid? Anyway, comment the ProcessCmdKey method and after BindingSource1.AddNew(), insert BindingSource1.AllowNew = False. Also, in UpdateProducts method, just _conn.Execute(sql, Obj) does not work?

@dr.null , comment the ProcessCmdKey method ok I do it. A one-row-only grid? I don't mean that but avoiding double addnew(). BindingSource1.AddNew(), insert BindingSource1.AllowNew = False Ok for this . if I commentout ProcessCmdKey How do I add a row?. I try something like _conn.Execute(sql, Obj) not updating the database

@dr.null , How can I handle  so there is no one row to be empty like a gif file in the post?

@dr.null , I updated the gif file in the post how can I handle no empty rows because of double addnew()

In ProcessCmdKey method add a condition to not call .AddNew if the productname property (and or other properties if you want) of the current row (DataBoundItem) is nothing or empty.

@dr.null , I've updated in the post in method ProcessCmdKey . Is it true?. Please guide me

Just require that data be entered, i.e. don't allow empty rows. If the user tries to add a row without having populated the previous one, they won't be allowed to.

if Not string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectDgv.ProductName) Then bindingSource1.AddNew() Else dgv.CurrentCell = dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(1) : dgv.BeginEdit(False)

Or If Not dgv.CurrentRow.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).Any(Function(cell) String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.FormattedValue?.ToString())) Then bindingSource1.AddNew() Else ... etc. to check all cells.

@dr.null , Thanks for reply. dgv.CurrentCell = dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(1)  for variable dgv I make like this Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView) but I have an error Error BC30451 'sender' is not declared. in method ProcessCmdKey

That's pseudo code son. Replace dgv with your DataGridView name. DataGridView1. The ProcessCmdKey is a Form method override, not a grid event handler that has sender param to do that cast. BRAIN-ON please.

@dr.null , . Replace dgv with your DataGridView name. DataGridView1. Sorry sir. If Not dgv.CurrentRow.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).Any(Function(cell) String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.FormattedValue?.ToString())) Then bindingSource1.AddNew() Else ... etc. I prefer and use this . In datagridview column ProductName and Qty readyonly = false. So after I fill in the productname and then qty then I use the tab whether I can directly position Edit in the productname column

@dr.null ,  is it possible after fill atau end edit in the productname then Position moves to qty column  And  then I use the tab Position moves to productname column?

@dr.null , I've updated the code in the method ProcessCmdKey So to move to the qty column then I press the F1 keyboard and after the update in the qty column then I have to press the Tab keyboard twice to move to the productname column. Maybe I'm still doing it wrong and please guide me from you

@dr.null , Hello sir, I have an error in event CellValidated when I use same form as view from new post this link . Please Guide me

@dr.null , If Not dgv.CurrentRow.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).Any(Function(cell) String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.FormattedValue?.ToString())) Then bindingSource1.AddNew() Else code from you for blank and how can i use it for empty and 0 values . I've updated the code in the post in cellendedit . Please Guide me
